# Client Server architecture for Iphone/android app

Tags: android, iphone, json, client-server

For an application (to be developed) on the Iphone/Android a Client-Server architecture is necessary. The clients (Smartphones) post a question and the answer needs to be given on a web page. For this structure three entities can be defined client, server (database) and webpage. The client needs to be updated when there is new information available given through use of the webpage.

What is a good starting point (framework). Questions that come into mind are data format of requests (probably JSON). What kind of backend software can be used? WHat is a good hosting plan if you consider that this app should scale.

I know it is a general question, but this is caused by the large number of possibilities (Ruby on rails, App engine google, php etc). And since I do not have previous experience I hope you can help me.

Grtz
Mv2k

Answer (score 0):

The only recommendation is that the transport format be compact and possibly compressed as well.  This is why JSON has been such a popular choice; it is both compact, compresses well, and is human readable.

The server side is a matter of your own preference and familiarity. Since you have no previous experience, no backend framework will make up for that better than another; choose one that you feel you can learn on your own.  If you know people who express a preference, ask if they would be willing to lend you some books and/or help.

Either way, this is a monumental education that cannot be given in an answer to one question.

Comment: Thnx for the advice. Any suggestion is welcome, this can help my search efforts. I also prefer frameworks that have a large community that is actively developed and has possibilities hosting-wise.

Comment: In that case, any of the major open source frameworks can suit your needs.  This includes Django, Ruby on Rails, and PHP/Zend.  All of these are actively maintained and support most backend SQL databases, such as MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL.  My personal preference (at this time) is Django and PostgreSQL; both of which have a relatively healthy community and are actively maintained.